# Using UTF-8 in Python 3 string literals

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, git-bash, python-unicode

I have a script I'm writing where I need to print the character sequence "Qä" to the terminal.  My terminal is using UTF-8 encoding.  My file has `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of it, which I think is not actually necessary for Python 3, but I put it there in case it made any difference.  In the code, I have something like

```
print("...Qä...")
```

This does not produce Qä.  Instead it produces Q▒.

I then tried

```
qa = "Qä".encode('utf-8')
print(f"...{qa}...")
```

This also does not produce Qä.  It produces 'Q\xc3\xa4'.

I also tried

```
qa = u"Qä"
print(f"...{qa}...")
```

This also produces Q▒.

However, I know that Python 3 can open files that contain UTF-8 and use the contents properly, so I created a file called qa.txt, pasted Qä into it, and then used

```
with open("qa.txt") as qa_file:
    qa = qa_file.read().strip()
print(f"...{qa}...")
```

This works.  However, it's beyond dumb that I have to create this file in order to print this string.  How can I put this text into my code as a string literal?

This question is NOT a duplicate of a question asking about Python 2.7, I am not using Python 2.7.

Comment: @Barmar: That dupe target was specifically about Python 2. This is a Python 3 question.

Comment: I suspect this is actually a terminal emulator issue. Your first code works for me in a Mac Terminal window.

Comment: My terminal can print this character perfectly well, as shown by the fact that reading it out of the file works.

Comment: Are `sys.stdout.encoding` and `sys.getdefaultencoding()` both "utf-8"?

Comment: Oh, that's interesting, `sys.getdefaultencoding()` is utf-8, but `sys.stdout.encoding` is cp1252 for some reason.

Comment: Is this a .py file saved to disk? I wonder if its something funky with your editor. If you had `test.py` with the single line `print("ä")`, does it fail. And if you read it as `open('test.py', 'rb').read()`, does that ä encode properly?

Comment: Yeah, what version of Windows? I'm not sure how you get to a utf-8 console. I don't use Windows often, but I think it switched at some point.

Comment: Windows 10.  I'm using Git Bash for the console, it has an options menu where you can set the encoding, and I've confirmed that it is set to UTF-8.  A new file with just `print("ä")` also doesn't work.

Comment: `sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')` might help. https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure I'm not sure what's causing this situation in the first place, though.

Comment: @user2357112, that did it, thanks!  If you post it as an answer I can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using Git Bash, on Windows. On Windows, [except](https://peps.python.org/pep-0528/) if stdio is connected to a standard Windows console (which I don't think Git Bash counts as), Python defaults the standard streams to a [locale encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-locale-encoding) of `'cp1252'`. Your terminal is set to expect UTF-8, not CP1252. You can [reconfigure](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure) the standard output stream to UTF-8 with

```
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

and similarly for stdin and stderr, or you can set the [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable to `utf-8` before running Python to change the default stdin/stdout/stderr encodings.